# ios simulator -- disable slow animations FOREVER?

Tags: ios-simulator

I'm accidentally turning slow animations about 50 times a day (I think it may because I'm using a virtual keyboard via Synergy) ... How can I disable slow animations in the simulator FOREVER?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

EDIT: Beginning with Xcode 5.0.1 with the iOS 7.0.3 simulator, <kbd>cmd</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> is now declared as the keyboard shortcut for Toggling Slow Animations and eliminates the observed informal shortcuts listed my my original answer.

---

This is something that I too encounter **all**...**the**...**time**, but I finally figured out what I was doing to cause it to be enabled in my simulator.

It turns out that iOS Simulator has a few shortcut key for enabling/disabling slow animations that are easily triggered when navigating through simulator (like gaining access to the multitasking bar) or when using system shortcuts for screen shots.  I've run across two undocumented keyboard shortcuts:

- Double-press of CMD+Shift (easy to inadvertently do when gaining access to the multitasking bar)

  - Alternate: Shift + Double-press of CMD
- Triple-press of Shift

Regardless of the method, if you have a debugger session running in Xcode, you can easily see the console message logging when these shortcuts have activated/deactivated slow-motion mode.

Unfortunately, there does not appear to be a way to disable these 'features' of iOS Simulator.  All I've been able to do so far is alter my workflow slightly to avoid key combinations that could trigger slow motion animation, but now have a quicker way to undo the behavior.

Comment: I wonder why they just didn't make a shortcut to the menu bar command.

Comment: Yes, I noticed... I'm very pleased :D

Comment: Mother... I thought I had a performance bug. I had the profiling tools out, reinstalled simulators, then reinstalled xcode. Finally found this. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Just double-press of Shift works for me in the emulator

Answer (score 0):

For the newer simulators just press CMD + T to check/uncheck slow animations.